# Creating a conditional on each sample in batch in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

I want to make a conditional on batch samples.

I have a binary classification task. The samples in my training set are in triplets and I have a label for every triplet

so `{1,0,0} , {0,1,0} and {0,0,1} will get the label 1.`

and `{0,1,1}, {1,0,1} and {1,1,0} will get the label 0.`

my test set is regular `0->0, 1->1` single sample-single label.

I thought about conditioning my batch on the triplet label, and thought about making a conditional on each triplet label.
If the label is 1 than I will combine the cross entropy loss of the possible triplets.

How do i loop through my labels `tensor` and combine the appropriate loss?

Thanks,
Tomer

Comment: Are the samples in the training set triplets related?

Comment: Yes, basically it's a variance of the test set.
I need to extract information from the triplets to the test set.
These are numbers (1 is odd, 0 is even) I can't specify much more than that.